# R_HOME Error with rpy2

Tags: python, r, windows-7, rpy2

I know there are quite a few posts on getting up and running with rpy2 on windows 7 32 bit.  I have referenced a good number of them and attempted their solutions, including the use of `PypeR`.

I dont explicitly have a R_HOME variable set in my path, but per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924917/trouble-installing-rpy2-on-win7-r-2-12-python-2-5), I confirmed that R is in my PATH (I can type `R` at the command line and get R to run) and even copied all of the files from the i386 folder to the parent `bin` folder.

My issue is pasted below.  Any thoughts?

```
In [5]: from rpy2 import robjects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1f019d00d232> in <module>()
----> 1 from rpy2 import robjects

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py in <module>()
     16 import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
     17
---> 18 from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
     19 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import *
     20 from rpy2.robjects.functions import Function, SignatureTranslatedFunction

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\robject.py in <module>()
      3 import rpy2.rinterface
      4
----> 5 rpy2.rinterface.initr()
      6
      7 import conversion

RuntimeError: R_HOME not defined.
```

Answer (score 15):

I confirm this issue is related to `R_HOME` variable not defined.

In my opinion, all of these issues are caused because the developers of `rpy2` package haven't documented properly the requirements of their software:

- Install `R`
- Create `R_HOME` system variable
- Add `R_HOME\bin` to the `PATH`, in order to execute `R` from `python`
- Add `R_HOME\bin\x64` to the `PATH`, in order to load `R.dll`
- Install package `tzlocal`

Comment: -2

what command do you use to install r? Does it matter if I install it on python 2.7 or 3? I am trying to have the installation done on jupiter notebook. specifically, Google Cloud Datalab Thanks, Eila

Comment: One additional step I had to do is get a POSIX `sh` in the PATH (like MSYS2 or git4windows)

Comment: If you already installed R, first find out the path of R by using `which R`. It gives a path like `/your_R_path/bin/R`. I then specify `R_HOME` with the path to the bin directory: `R_HOME=/your_R_path/bin/`. Then go back to python and install. It works for me.

Comment: No commands given in the answer. Why so?

Comment: Interesting that this is not documented somewhere on the `rpy2` documentation page. I agree, this should be added!

Answer (score 5):

With help from the comment above, I got moving in the proper direction. I created the R_HOME as a SYSTEM variable.  That didn't work right away, as I was getting an R_USER not defined error.

To get everything the import above to work without error, I simply re-installed the rpy2 exectuable from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) after defining the R_HOME.  No errors.

In summary, key was o have R_HOME set PRIOR TO installing rpy2.

Comment: This seems odd. I remember that setting environment variables in Windows required to log-out/log-in (user-level variable) and reboot (system-level variable). May be this was the issue ?