# Installing rpy2 on macOS -- problem with R_HOME variable

Tags: python, r, installation

I want to import libraries in my python code, so I can interface my Rcode using Python. I've installed rpy2 using pip `pip rpy2 install` However, I'm getting the error "**ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation**" in my python session.

System:

MacOS: Mojave 10.14.5

Python: 3.7.4 (using eclipse & pydev to build scripts)

R: 3.5.3

I ran this code in terminal `export R_HOME=$(R RHOME)` to set my R_HOME variable. Then to check I ran     `python -m ryp2.situation` to check my output and see if the R_HOME variable was correctly added.

> Python version:
> 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23)  [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] Looking for R's HOME:

> ```
> Environment variable R_HOME: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
> Calling `R RHOME`: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
> InstallPath in the registry: *** Only available on Windows *** R version:
> In the PATH: R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
> Loading R library from rpy2: OK Additional directories to load R packages from: None
> ```

So now it looks like I have R_HOME as a variable, but I still get the same error in executing my python code. I have tried to uninstall rpy2 in the terminal and reinstall using terminal following some of the logic in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573988/r-home-error-with-rpy2). I'm stuck and not sure what I should try next, so appreciate the help.

Here is the python code I want to run:

```py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

    
packageNames = ('pdftools', 'dplyr', 'stringi', 'knitr', 'markdown', 'rmarkdown')
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
    
packnames_to_install = [x for x in packageNames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
    
if len(packnames_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))
```

Comment: It looks like the default OSX location of the R executable is `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources`. So I needed to set an environment variable (in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`) with the line `export R_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip uninstall rpy2
pip list --outdated
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install rpy2
```