# Error while downloading rpy2 package on python

Tags: python, windows, rpy2

I'm getting this error while trying to install rpy2 package:

> RuntimeError: R_HOME not defined, and no R command in the PATH.

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix this?

Comment: does this question solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573988/r-home-error-with-rpy2

Comment: Try not to use images of code on your questions. Better to paste the stacktrace here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You could use Docker or WSL2 instead, but you will still need to refine R_HOME and put R executable on your PATH

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but on the [rpy2 package page](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/overview.html#installation), they said :

> Running rpy2 on Windows is currently not supported although relative success was recently reported with the lastest in the 3.3.x series.