# How to set R_Home in the environment or registry in PyCharm (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, r, pycharm, anaconda

I am trying to run some code in PyCharm that also needs an R environment within Anaconda.

I have used the https://support.anaconda.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023857134-Setting-up-rpy2-on-Windows, to add the relevant paths of Anaconda and also R to my environment variables.

Restarted the computer etc, and I still get an error in PyCharm saying that the R_Home must be set in the environment or registry.

I have seen this post on Stack [R_HOME Error with rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573988/r-home-error-with-rpy2), however, I would like to be able to use PyCharm to get this working.

I can see on my friends computer that when they did exactly the same steps (environment variables are the same), they get a C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1, when they use conda info --env in Pycharm, its also present in their environment in the Anaconda Navigator.

Why isn't it working for me? Any advice or further workarounds would be appreciated