# "Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH"

Tags: rpy2

> "Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH"

after runing  `[ rpy2-2.5.6]$ python setup.py install` commands in my redhat server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you give us more details please ?

Comment: I am trying to install rpy2-2.5.6 in my server ( redhat ). According to installation guideline when I execute "python setup.py install" commands it returns  "Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH". How can I overcome this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [trouble installing rpy2 on win7 (R 2.12, Python 2.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924917/trouble-installing-rpy2-on-win7-r-2-12-python-2-5)

Comment: As the linked question describes, you need to set up your environment variable. http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/red-hat/path-variable.html

Comment: I have added the R path "/usr/lib64/R" in .bashrc file but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to install libraries always with pip instead of messing around yourself with setup.py files.

I run into the same error under windows 8, R Version 3.3.1 and Python 2.7, 32bit. The solution is easy but for this case the normal pip install rpy2 does not work.

Instead try to use the Windows-Binaries you find them here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2. Download the suiting whl file for your configuration. Then go to your download folder in cmd and simply use:

```
pip install rpy2-2.7.8-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Note, make sure you adapt this code to your download file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this happens to me because I'm trying to install on a python version 2.6.5 and the `setup.py` script tries to use a method `subprocess.check_output` that is new on 2.7, hence it raises an exception that leads to the this message. It seems to be wise to use a 2.7 or later version, because the `check_output` method is used several times in the `setup.py` script.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Mac using python 2.7:
In my `~/.profile` (or use `~/.bashrc`) 
I set:

```
export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
export PATH=$R_HOME:$PATH
```

sourced it (`source ~/.profile`) and then did the standard

```
pip install rpy2
```